# Copy temp files with randomly generated string in the filename with Ant

Tags: java, ant

I created some temp files with a custom task in the system's default temp folder. Depending on different configuration, there will be two or three files -- one is **codebaseXX.log** (**the XX part means a number string that Java created automatically for the temp file**) and the other(s) is(are) **local-changes-XX.diff**.

Currently, in the file-generating task, I put the full name of the first file and "local-changes*.diff" into two properties (say file1 and file2). And then I copy them back using `<copy>`:

```
<copy todir="log/configs" >
    <fileset dir="${tmpdir}">
        <include name="${file1}" />
        <include name="${file2}" />
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

For example, I may have the following files generated:

> codebase529846369165360813.log
>   local-changes-original5410491830492606676.diff
>   local-changes-simple7778114354296759394.diff (if exists)

and I want to **copy exactly what is exactly generated this time (because there are changes that some old files are not deleted)** and **rename them**, like this:

> codebase.log
>   local-changes-original.diff
>   local-changes-simple.diff (if exists)

**My question is: My task knows exactly which files is generated, but how to tell the other tasks that those files should be processed?  Also, how to smartly rename them?**

Comment: Have you considered using ANT tempfile task to manage these temporary files for you? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html

Comment: @MarkO'Connor .. `tempfile` is the perfect/correct way to go. 1 up for you :)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using ANT [tempfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html) task to manage these temporary files for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ant-contrib library which allows you to have variable . In your generating task remember filenames and pass them to other tasks.

Comment: The problem is, how can I provide a list in string form (like "a,b,c") to a fileset?